# ¿Quién me puede explicar el significado de la variable $cant?

Tags: php

Tengo problemas al modificar unos campos para generar un pdf y me encontré con la variable `$cant` y como soy muy nuevo en esto pido que por favor me ayuden, necesito ingresar una nueva columna entre und y Referencia y eliminar precio unitario y valor pero no se como hacerlo.

```
$pdf = new PDF('P','mm','Letter');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(10,5,'Stk',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,5,'Loc',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,5,'Unidad',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Referencia',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(95,5,'Articulo',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Precio/Unit',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Valor',1,1,'C');

$select = "SELECT p.*, r.B001 ";
$select .= "FROM pedidos_detalle p LEFT JOIN referencias_ubicacion r ON p.referencia = r.referencia ";
$select .= "WHERE ID_PEDIDO =".$_GET['ped']." ";
$select .= "ORDER BY REPLACE(r.B001,'-','') DESC, p.REFERENCIA"; 

$rs=mysqli_query($mysqli, $select);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',10);   
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){
    $sql = "SELECT (saldo_inicial + compras + entradas_especiales - ventas - salidas_especiales) AS saldo FROM saldosbodega_2000 WHERE bodega=001 AND mes = (convert(varchar(6),getdate(),112)) AND referencia = '$row[2]'";

    $rs1=mssql_query($sql,$link);
    $row1=mssql_fetch_row($rs1);
    $cant = number_format($row1[0],0, ',', '.');
    $pdf->Cell(10,5,$cant,1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(20,5,$row[9],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(10,5,number_format($row[5],0, ',', '.'),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,$row[2],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(85,5,$row[3],1,0,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,number_format($row[4],2, ',', '.'),1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,5,number_format($row[7],2, ',', '.'),1,1,'C');
}
$pdf->SetFont('Times','I',12);
$pdf->Cell(150,5,'','L');
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'IVA   ',1,0,'R');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->Cell(25,5,number_format($GLOBALS['tot_iva'],2, ',', '.'),1,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(150,5,'','L');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','I',12);
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Descuento   ',1,0,'R');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->Cell(25,5,number_format($GLOBALS['tot_dcto'],2, ',', '.'),1,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(150,5,'Observaciones:','L');
$pdf->Cell(25,5,'Total   ',1,0,'R');
$pdf->Cell(25,5,number_format($GLOBALS['total'],2, ',', '.'),1,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',10);
$pdf->MultiCell(200,5,strtoupper($obser),1,'L');

$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(10,5,'',0,1,'');
$pdf->Cell(25,4,'Tarjeta: '.$_GET['tar'],0,1,'');
$pdf->Cell(25,4,$_GET['usu'],0,1,'');
$pdf->Cell(25,4,date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),0,1,'');

mssql_close($link);
mysqli_close($mysqli);

$pdf->Output('pedido_picking/PEDW'.str_pad($id,8,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).'.pdf','F');
//$pdf->Output('','I');
header('Location:proceso_picking_pdf.html?ped=PEDW'.str_pad($id,8,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT));`
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial de php, la cual también está en español: http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php

**number_format** — Formatear un número con los millares agrupados

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )
```

Esta función acepta uno, dos, o cuatro parámetros (no tres):

Si solo se proporciona un parámetro, number será formateado sin decimales, pero con una coma (",") entre cada grupo de millares.

Si se proporcionan dos parámetros, number será formateado con tantos decimales como se hayan definido en decimals colocando un punto (".") delante, y una coma (",") entre cada grupo de millares.

Si se proporcionan los cuatro parámetros, number será formateado con tantos decimales como hayamos definido en decimals, dec_point sustituirá al punto (".") como seperador de los decimales y el separador por defecto de los millares, la coma (","), será sustituida por thousands_sep.

**number**
El número al que dar formato.

**decimals**
Establece el número de puntos decimales.

**dec_point**
Establece el separador para los decimales.

**thousands_sep**
Establece el separador para los millares.

---

¿Qué hace entonces en este caso?

Tomar el primer valor (o aquel que tenga la llave 0) del array $row (si no sabes que es un array, de nuevo mira la documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php ), le 'quita' los decimales que pueda tener, utiliza la coma (,) para separar los decimales (aunque en este caso no habrán) y por último utiliza el punto (.) para separar los millares.

Answer (score 0):

Es una variable que cambia el formato del valor de $row1 de separador de miles de , a ., a lo cual podría decir que $row1 obtiene el primer registro del resulset de la consulta a la base de datos.

```
$cant = number_format($row1[0],0, ',', '.');
```